# PHP - in_array() issues - Won't check correctly

Tags: php

I have an array called `$sum`. In `$sum` I add the md5 hash of each file in `$files`. If that array does NOT contains the current `$hash`, I want it to do something (like saying it doesn't contains it).

```
$sum = array();

foreach($files as $file) {
    $hash = md5_file($file);
    $sum[] = $hash;
    if(in_array($hash, $sum) == FALSE) {
            echo $hash . ' is not in the array';
    }
}
```

If I check the content of `$sum` (by changing the if-statement's `$hash` to something random like "12345"), I can see the hashes being added to the array.

Why does that if-statement not work correctly? I cannot seem to wrap my head around why it won't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `== FALSE` part. Because `in_array()` already returns true if it is already in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add new hash value before if, so it always true. Just change their place

```
if(in_array($hash, $sum) == FALSE) {
    echo $hash . ' is already in the array';
}
$sum[] = $hash;
```

Comment: Ah of course. I completely didn't check this.. Thank you for telling me!

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

> Returns TRUE if needle is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

Your IF statement is wrong.

Anyway, if you add the hash the line before, the IF will always be TRUE: I don't get what you are trying to do... :)

Comment: I reversed my whole question from being "is in the array" to "not being in the array", and I forgot to change something. I read it through twice but I didn't catch the error. I edited the post, and figured it was because `$sum = $hash` is being set before the if-statement... Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking for the existence of a value then your logic is reversed

```
if(in_array($hash, $sum)) { //means the item is in the array
        echo $hash . ' is already in the array';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Search for `== TRUE`, not `== FALSE`

Comment: "Why does that if-statement not work correctly?"    it answers the question.